# How to show JSON array data in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

## JSON VIEW

```
//url data

{   "status": {  
"mission_id": "6",  
"mission": " Mission:<\/strong> <\/em><\/h1>\r\n\r\n     The mission of the Greater Fort Wayne Hispanic Chamber of Commerce is to advocate, promote, and facilitate the success of Hispanic-owned businesses which will fully participate in the growth, development and education of Allen and surrounding counties. \r\n    \r\n     In addition, the Chamber strives to focus on the most effective and coordinated Hispanic business development efforts maximizing public and private sector involvement.
  }
}
```

## My Code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad  {   
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURLRequest *req=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://edutimeapp.com/toshow/chamber-of-commerc/ws/fetch_mission.php"]];            
 response =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];


[self.textmission setText: textarray];   //textaray NSArray object name and textmission is UITextView outlet name.     


_textmission.scrollEnabled = YES;      


 self.textmission.editable = NO;
}
```

## connection

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data    
{    
[response appendData:data];    
NSLog(@"error receving data %@",response);    
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response    
{
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{    
NSError *error;

NSLog(@"Error in receiving data %@",error);
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
NSLog(@"response data %@",json);

NSArray* results = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
textarray = [results valueForKey:@"mission"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this below code,

```
YourTextViewName.text = [self convertHtmlPlainText:[[json objectForKey:@"status"] valueForKey:@"mission"]];
```

convert HTML to Normal String:

```
-(NSString*)convertHtmlPlainText:(NSString*)HTMLString{
    NSData *HTMLData = [HTMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:HTMLData options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:NULL error:NULL];
    NSString *plainString = attrString.string;
    return plainString;
}
```

hope its helpful

Comment: what is the problem, what is textArray?

Comment: text array is a array name and in this  store a key value data

Comment: ok what is the problem, html tags not removing ah?

Comment: Problem is that do not show JSON  data on textview.

Comment: if you use array, its not neccessary i have update the code above, check it, its working for me

Comment: i again used your code and run successfully :)   Thankyou so much ravi

Comment: ya its small mistake, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have to first remove html content using attribute string like this i have use like this

```
NSString *htmlString = [[[ResponseNotification objectForKey:@"notifs"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"content"];
    NSLog(@"%@",htmlString);

    NSMutableAttributedString *newStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    [newStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:12.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, [newStr length])];
    [newStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [newStr length])];
```

Comment: no helpfully your code :( please suggest another one ans.